# Makefile C best way to include header file for installed library and to link against a library

Tags: c, makefile, linker, include

I usually use eclipse to build my C project. But I'm trying to build a make file now which is below.

My questions are:

1) what is the best way to specify an include path for the compiler to a header file for an installed library in `/usr/local/include/upm`

2) To a library called `upmc-rn2483` for the linking phase

```
TARGET_EXEC ?= app.out

BUILD_DIR ?= ./build
SRC_DIRS ?= ./src


SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *.cpp -or -name *.c -or -name *.s)
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)

INC_DIRS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -type d)
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS)) -I/usr/local/include/upm

CPPFLAGS ?= $(INC_FLAGS) -MMD -MP 

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

LD_FLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib/upm -L/usr/lib/rabbitmq 

LIBS = -lrabbitmq -lupmc-rn2483 -lupmc-rn2903 -lupmc-utilities

# c source
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c
    $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@.o
    $(CC) $(LD_FLAGS)    $@.o -o $@ $LIBS



.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR)

-include $(DEPS)

MKDIR_P ?= mkdir -p
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) what is the best way to specify an include path for the compiler to a header file

Add a `-I` for the include directory to your preprocessor flags.

```
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS)) -I/usr/local/include/upm
```

> To a library called upmc-rn2483 for the linking phase

Add a `-L` flag for the directory in which the library resides an a `-l` flag for the library itself to the loader flags. If the library is `libupmc-rn2483.a` in `/usr/local/lib/upm` add

```
LD_FLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib/upm -lupmc-rn2483
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply. I've updated my original question. I am getting an error `error: IBS: No such file or directory` ? I think its missing the L from LIBS?

Comment: Multi char macro names need round brackets. It is seeing $L and then IBS. I think you want $(LIBS)